# MS Word - convert outline to a chart?

Tags: microsoft-word, outline, tree-view

I have an outline in MS Word I would like to convert to some kind of tree chart to visualize it. Is that possible?

Comment: This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far and exactly what you expect to accomplish. Screen shots would be helpful. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Do you use MS Word? Or know what a tree chart is? Because if you do you would understand this question perfectly well.

Comment: Don't take it personal. This isn't about me using Word or understanding what a tree chart is. It is about the quality of your question. Did you read the "How to ask" link I gave you? Please go read it because it can help you improve your question (which may resolve the lack of response it has received since posting).